# pandas aggregate function with multiple output columns

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions

I am trying to define an aggregation function with more than one OUTPUT columns, which i would like to use as follows

```
df.groupby(by=...).agg(my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns)
```

any idea how to do it ?

i tried things like

```
def my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns(slice_values):
    return {'col_1': -1,'col_2': 1}
```

but this will logically output the dictionary {'col_1': -1,'col_2': 1} in a single column...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible, because `agg` working with all columns separately - first process first column, then second.... to the end.

Solution is [`flexible apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) and for return multiple output add `Series` if output is more scalars.

```
def my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns(slice_values):
    return pd.Series([-1, 1], index=['col_1','col_2'])

df.groupby(by=...).apply(my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,1,2,2,3], B=[4,5,6,7,2], C=[1,2,4,6,9]))
print (df)

def my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns(slice_values):
    #print each group
    #print (slice_values)
    a = slice_values['B'] + slice_values['C'].shift()
    print (type(a))
    return a

<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

df = df.groupby('A').apply(my_aggregation_function_with_multiple_columns)
print (df)
A   
1  0     NaN
   1     6.0
2  2     NaN
   3    11.0
3  4     NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

The question can be interpreted in multiple ways. The following offers a solution for computing more than one output column, giving the possibility to use a different function for each column.

The example uses the same Pandas DataFrame df as the answer above:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=[1,1,2,2,3], B=[4,5,6,7,2], C=[1,2,4,6,9]))
```

As a function of the groups in A the sum of the values in B is computed and put in one column, and the number of values (count) in B is computed and put in another column.

```
df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg({'B': {'B1':sum, 'B2': "count"}})
```

Because dictionaries with renaming will be deprecated in future versions the following code may be better:

```
df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg({'B': {sum, "count"}})
```

The next example shows how to do this if you want to have different computations on different columns, for computing the sum of B and mean of C:

```
df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False).agg({'B': sum, 'C': "mean"})
```